# how to get the host name of the node where a POD is running from within POD

Tags: kubernetes

is it possible to get the host name or ip of the node where a kubernetes pod is running from with POD ?
does kubernetes exposes any environment variable within POD with host name or ip where the POD is running ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it like this

```
env:
  - name: NODE_IP
    valueFrom:
      fieldRef:
        fieldPath: status.hostIP
```